# How to run something after Windows logon is fully done?

Tags: shell, session, service, startup, authentication

I have a system service running on my Windows machine that can impersonate the currently logged on user and launch applications on their behalf (including UI apps).

It works fine when the user is already logged on into their interactive session, their Desktop is created, and so on.

The startup of the service is Automatic, so it is started automatically after each reboot. If it attempts to run some program (that needs UI access) immediately after the service is started, that program may fail - possibly because the autologon process is still in progress, the Desktop is not created yet, etc.

The question is: if the service starts "early", how can it wait for the interactive session to be fully initialized (apart from waiting some arbitrary time, which is not optimal)?

Or, can the service be started "late"? Is there a registry key, or a folder, or something else, that I can use to delay the service startup to the moment when the Shell is ready and it is safe to launch UI applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest two ways to "execute some code when a user logs on" is to write a .bat file, and either:

1) Put the .bat file in the startup folder
     <= Note: Windows 7/Vista has a new location for "Startup folder"

... or ...

2) Create a new Task that calls the .bat file at login

I option "2)" gives you finer control.  It also allows the .bat file to "Run as Administrator" if needed.

If you'd like to make the .bat file pause briefly (e.g. to make sure things are completely initialized", you can add "ping -w" to your .bat file.

EXAMPLE:

```
@rem Waits 5 seconds before continuing
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that solution 2 works just fine (I am calling schtasks.exe to create/delete that ONLOGON task programmatically). That ping trick is neat (another option is to use timeout /t).